# ScrollMagic parallax - animation plays immediately instead of on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the ScrollMagic jquery plugin on a site. I have a few elements that animate their vertical alignment on scroll, however simple background image parallax isnt working. in its current implementation, the parallax happens on page load rather than being tied to page scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      var tween = new TimelineMax ()
        .add([TweenMax.staggerFromTo(".masthead", 5, {backgroundPosition: "0 0"}, {backgroundPosition: "0 100px"} )]);                              
            var scene = new ScrollScene({duration: 1200})
                            .setTween(tween)
                            .addTo(controller);
                             scene.addIndicators();
        });
```